# Flutter-Use Android XML as Widget

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-platform-channel

Is it possible to use Android XML as a widget in Flutter? I wanna use mapbox but some methods dont exist in ios or android. I wanna use android and ios views in flutter and use all methods as native. How can i do it?

Comment: and what do you mean by "Android XML"? android uses xml files in multiple places, wher the most common is `res/layout/*.xml` files, is it what you mean?

Comment: @pskink  I wanna use res/layout/*.xml files in flutter as a widget.

Comment: in flutter? no, it is not possible

Answer (score 2):

No it's not possible to use andriod xml as a widget in Flutter

Comment: Is there any method to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Flutter has enough widgets for creating any UI you want. I recommend you use Material Components widgets (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/material) if you wanna make screen similar to Android.

If you need to parse XML, use this lib
https://pub.dev/packages/xml